# Symfony CMF block bundle, Imagine block not displaying Image in front end (MAC MAMP)

Tags: php, symfony, sylius, symfony-cmf

I am working on a new Sylius project and I have been struggling with this many days and still couldn't find a solution. After looking into it, my problem is that the image in Imagine block not rendered or "resolved" with liip imagine bundle in front end. I have checked the phpcr notes and my block does saved successfully

```
ROOT:
cms:
  blocks:
      contact:
      block-1:
      block-2:
      block-3:
      welcome-text:
      ccc:
          image:
              jcr:content:
  pages:
      terms-of-service:
      about-us:
  menus:
  medias:
  routes:
      terms-of-service:
      about:
```

As you can see, but when I render this block in front end using `{{ sonata_block_render({'name': '/cms/blocks/ccc'}) }}` the image is not showing, instead the image URL rendered is something like `http://sylius:8888/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/slideshow_small/cms/blocks/ccc/image`

Does anyone know what is missing or what might cause the problem?

Thanks

Comment: did you configure the imagine filter for slideshow_small? what do you see when you open thta url in your browser?

Comment: What happens if you try to access this URL directly http://sylius:8888/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/slideshow_small/cms/blocks/ccc/image ?